# Flex - style TextArea with CSS

Tags: css, apache-flex, textarea

Just wondering if it's possible to apply a *.css to a spark TextArea? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace local "*";
    s|Label
    {
        color:#33494A;
        fontFamily: "ApexNew";
        fontSize: 14pt;
    }
    s|TextArea
    {
        color:#33494A;
        fontFamily: "ApexNew";
        fontSize: 14pt;
    }
    @font-face
    {
        fontFamily: "ApexNew";
        src:url('font/ApexNew-Medium.otf');
    }
</fx:Style>
```

or

```
<fx:Style source="something.css"/>
```

[something.css]

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
@namespace local "*";
s|Label
{
    color:#33494A;
    fontFamily: "ApexNew";
    fontSize: 14pt;
}
s|TextArea
{
    color:#33494A;
    fontFamily: "ApexNew";
    fontSize: 14pt;
}
@font-face
{
    fontFamily: "ApexNew";
    src:url('font/ApexNew-Medium.otf');
}
```

Comment: Where does the CSS code go? I'm afraid I don't know anything about styling flex components

Comment: You can include the CSS either inline or put it in a separate css file, I'll edit the answer above to show it inline, for the separate css file you would just copy the contents of the <fx:Style> tag into another file called, something.css then do a <fx:Style source="something.css"/>