# styling images in spark textarea

Tags: css, apache-flex, textarea, flex4, flex-spark

This [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c2028ff4112df207af8b-8000.html) shows how you can have Images in your spark TextArea and set their `float` and `paddingLeft`/`paddingRight` properties:

```
<s:RichEditableText id="myRET1" width="300">
    <s:textFlow>
        <s:TextFlow columnWidth="290">
            <s:p id="p1">Images in a flow are a good thing. For example, here is a float. 
            <s:img id="image1" float="none" source="@Embed(source='../assets/bulldog.jpg')" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10">
            </s:img>
            Don't you agree? It should show on the left. If it doesn't show up on the left, then it is a bug. You can submit bugs at http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/. You can set how the float is positioned within
            the paragraph by using the ComboBox below. You can select left, right, start, end, or none. This example does not use the clearFloats property. That is in a different example.</s:p>
        </s:TextFlow>
    </s:textFlow>
</s:RichEditableText>
```

Is it possible to specify the image's float/padding via [Flex's CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183290/flex-style-textarea-with-css)?

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible to specify the image via css :

1)create a skin contains this image and those properties(padding)

2)create file css contains name space of component and call class reference (the class passed as parameter skins)

3)define in file mxml the style name equal the name space specified in steps 1